# Exponential basis for $L^2([0,\infty))$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Does $L^2([0,\infty))$ have a Hilbert basis consisting of "nice" exponentials, $a_ne^{b_nx}, a_n>0, b_n\in\mathbb{C}$, where "nice" means that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are given by a simple, possibly recursive, formula?

Do the exponentials $\{e^{s x}\}_{s\in\mathbb{C}}$ even span $L^2([0,\infty))$? I feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: Laplace transform comes at least close to addressing your second question... In what context do you ask these questions?

Comment: @paul I keep track, numerically, of information on $[0,\infty)$. As time progresses, the information shifts, $f\mapsto Sf:= f(\cdot + dt)$. I need to store the information discretely and it would be good if $S$ mapped my discretization to itself. That would be the case if I stored coefficients with respect to a basis such as the one described. I could of course use step functions, but then the number of step functions would need to scale like $T/dt$ and for reasons I need very small $dt$ while my information is rather low frequency

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm a little occupied with other things currently, but I'll come back to this if no one else has anything helpful...

Answer (score 1):

For a *discrete* decomposition, the closest natural/well-studied thing I can think of would be functions of the form $H_{2n}(x)\,e^{-x^2/2}$, where $H_n$ are Hermite polynomials, and we only need the even-index ones. Up to normalizations these give an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,+\infty)$. Similarly, one could use $H_{2n+1}(x)e^{-x^2/2}$. Differentiation maps between the two orthogonal families.

These are eigenfunctions for the "quantum harmonic oscillator" $-{\partial^2\over \partial x^2}+x^2$, which has compact resolvent, and is essentially self-adjoint, so gives $L^2(\mathbb R)$ an orthogonal basis of eigenfunctions. The so-called (google-able) "ladder operators" $i{\partial\over \partial x}\pm ix$ exactly map (up to determinable constants) $H_ne^{-x^2/2}\to H_{n\mp 1}e^{-x^2/2}$. (Yes, note the opposite-ness of signs.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the discrete shift doesn't preserve these families but the derivative does, so I could use a finite subfamily and then approximate the shift by a multiple of the derivative, and ignore the one term that goes outside of the finite subspace? I'll give it a try.

Comment: In the meantime, could you also briefly talk about how the Laplace transform answers my second question? The way I understand things the inverse Laplace transform falls just short of proving that $L^2([0,\infty))$-exponentials span $L^2([0,\infty))$

Comment: Right, Laplace transform does not talk about or produce orthogonal bases, etc., but the integral formulas do perhaps the best that can be done with pure exponentials.